# Swift dispatch_async from function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, dispatch-async

How can i wait until function get all data from alamofire get request?

GetData.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import ObjectMapper

func getStartData() -> Void {
    let sharedBranch = BranchSingleton.sharedInstance
    let sharedArticle = ArticleSingleton.sharedInstance

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Config().apiBranch)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(result.value!)
            for obj in jsonObj {
                let branch = Mapper<Branch>().map(obj.1.rawString()!)
                sharedBranch.addBranch(branch!)
            }
    }
    Alamofire.request(.GET, Config().apiArticle)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(result.value!)
            for obj in jsonObj {
                let article = Mapper<Article>().map(obj.1.rawString()!)
                sharedArticle.addArticle(article!)
            }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getStartData() // need to wait until all requests are finished then do print
        print(sharedArticle.articleList)

    }

}
```

SingletonObj.swift file:

```
import Foundation

class BranchSingleton {
    var branchList: [Branch] = []

    class var sharedInstance: BranchSingleton {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: BranchSingleton = BranchSingleton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func addBranch(branch: Branch) {
        branchList.append(branch)
    }
}
class ArticleSingleton {
    var articleList: [Article] = []

    class var sharedInstance: ArticleSingleton {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: ArticleSingleton = ArticleSingleton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func addArticle(article: Article) {
        articleList.append(article)
    }
}
```

i need to wait until `getStartData()` finish, then pring singleton array..

How can i do that?

This getStartData contains more than 2 requests, but i just gave example with 2..

Comment: Wait for what? What is it that you can do only after all the data have come in?

Comment: Remove loading spinner, or something like that.. after all requests in that `getStartData()` are finished..

Comment: No, not "something like that". Be specific. What reason could you possibly having for waiting until it is all over? Look, you're thinking about this all wrong. You do not "wait". You must not make the user "wait". You do stuff asynchronously and just keep updating as you go.

Comment: I know that, but i wanna remove spinner after both requests are done, it there any elegant way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a non-question. There is *no reason* to "wait". Nor can you. You just do what you do, asynchronously. Meanwhile the interface must stay active; the user must be able to continue to work. Thus there is nothing to "wait" *for*.

Now, if the question is, how can you send a signal in some elegant way to the rest of your app when all of the requests are done, one good answer is to use NSProgress. All the different requests can contribute to a common NSProgress object. The nice thing is that its `fractionCompleted` is observable with KVO, so when it comes greater-than-or-equal-to `1.0`, you're done.

But you don't actually need the NSProgress; you could just increment or decrement an instance variable that's KVO-observable (being careful about threading, of course). If you know there are `n` processes, then you could just start a variable at `n` and have each process decrement it when it completes; a `didSet` observer on the variable can then take action when we hit zero.

The point is: you don't "wait": you just have all the different activities contribute to some common central value that "knows" when this means we've "finished" and can then take action.

Comment: Do you have any example for that?

Comment: There's a whole WWDC 2015 video on NSProgress if you're really interested. But you don't actually need the NSProgress; you could just increment or decrement an instance variable that's KVO-observable (being careful about threading, of course). The point is: you don't "wait": you just have all the different activities contribute to some common central value that "knows" when this means we've "finished" and can then take action. — I think I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I will give it a try with your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt says, you can't, and shouldn't, try to wait until Alamofire is done with your request. That's like hiring somebody to run an errand for so you can work and then stopping everything and sitting by the door until they get back. You might as well have run the errand yourself.

Dropping the analogy, you might as well have performed the task synchronously. However, synchronous networking is a very bad idea. It freezes the UI until the network request is complete, which can be a very long wait if something goes wrong.

An async method like Alamofire's request method takes a completion block, a block of code that should be run when the work is finished.

The request method returns immediately, before the request has even been sent to the server, much less completed.

Instead of waiting around for the request to complete, you should refactor your getStartData method to take a completion handler, and use **that** to respond once the work is done:

```
func getStartData(completion: () -> void) -> Void {
    let sharedBranch = BranchSingleton.sharedInstance
    let sharedArticle = ArticleSingleton.sharedInstance

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Config().apiBranch)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(result.value!)
            for obj in jsonObj {
                let branch = Mapper<Branch>().map(obj.1.rawString()!)
                sharedBranch.addBranch(branch!)
            }
    }
    Alamofire.request(.GET, Config().apiArticle)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(result.value!)
            for obj in jsonObj {
                let article = Mapper<Article>().map(obj.1.rawString()!)
                sharedArticle.addArticle(article!)
            }
    //At this point the Alamofire .GET request for Config().apiArticle 
    //is complete. Call our completion block (passed in as a parameter)
    completion()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getStartData() 
        {
          //This is a "trailing closure", a block of code passed to getStartData
          print("At this point, we've finished getting our data from Alamofire.")
          print(sharedArticle.articleList)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your `getStartData` method makes 2 `Alamofire.request()` commands in a row. If the second request requires that the first request be finished then you will need to restructure that code so that the second Alamofire request is inside the completion block for the first call. (That's more editing than I'm in the mood to do at the moment.)